# Arrange line in front of bars in Matplotlib plot with double y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot a graph with two y axes, and I want the left y axis to show a line according to which the x axis is sorted, and the right y axis to show bars. My problem is that the secondary y axis hides the first y axis, as shown in the attached figure. The code I use is the following:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()    
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
p1 = ax1.plot(ind, total_facilities, '--bo')
width = 1
p2 = ax2.bar(ind, pdb_facilities, width, color='gray',edgecolor = "none")
plt.xlim([-1,len(total_facilities)])
ax1.set_yscale('symlog')
```

When I re-arrange the axes so I plot the blue line in the secondary axis the line goes in front of the gray bars but then it's confusing because I want the x-axis to be ordered according to the values of the primary y axis. Is there any way to bring the blue line in front while keeping it in the primary y axis?

[image]

Comment: Try ax1.plot(ind, total_facilities, '--bo', zorder=10)

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work

Comment: @Sait But thanks to your comment I found the solution here: 
http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Control-twinx-series-zorder-ax2-series-behind-ax1-series-or-place-ax2-on-left-ax1-on-right-td12994.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I can switch the place of the secondary y axis, so the secondary y axis is plotted on the left and the primary on the right:

```
ax2 = ax1.twinx()
p1 = ax2.plot(ind, total_facilities, '--bo')
p2 = ax1.bar(ind, pdb_facilities, width, color='gray',edgecolor = "none")
plt.xlim([-1,len(total_facilities)])
ax2.set_yscale('symlog')
ax1.yaxis.tick_right()
ax2.yaxis.tick_left()
plt.show()
```